# Highcharts dashboard - custom component

Tags: highcharts

I would love to know whether it's possible to add your own custom component into an edit mode in highcharts dashboard. More precisely there's an "Add component" button.

I could only find adding your own custom component, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: The documentation says: "The sidebar lists the component types provided by the Dashboards API. Please note that custom, user-defined components will not be located there." ~ https://www.highcharts.com/docs/dashboards/edit-mode#add-component

But I haven't found any information anywhere on how it could be added there. I would suggest you create a feature request on the official GitHub repository, it will probably get a positive response and can be implemented quickly, and before that you may get a workaround. I'll vote for this feature myself, so post the link here later 